# Missing CORS configurationSource for spring security dsl

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to replace spring following security config with new dsl:

```kotlin
http.cors().configurationSource { CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues() }
```

However MVC dsl for CORS doesn't contain an ability to set configuration source (`CorsDsl` class). I can see that in WebFlux version (`ServerCorsDsl` class) there is

```kotlin
var configurationSource: CorsConfigurationSource? = null
```

Does anyone know why there is no such property for MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corresponding issue was created and fixed in 5.5.0 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9314